# Show battery percentage at fullscreen software

Tags: windows-8, display, battery

Using a Win8 notebook and running fullscreen software, 
I need a tool that shows me the current battery percentage in real time while I'm inside the fullscreen program.

Is there anything that could help me so I don't have to tab on the desktop all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the application [Battery Bar](https://batterybarpro.com) and why Im suggesting is that this software provides an option to install the floating widget which I think that it matches your requirement

> You can download the free version or BatteryBar Pro version which
>   costs only $8 for a lifetime license.

Some screenshots provided here with my answer to take your decision to go ahead with this application or not :D screenshots are from the Pro Version

[image]

[image]

> **I downloaded the free version to check its functionality**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could you check if the Widget is visible in fullscreen applications? Basicly a friend asked me this, he wants to play games on his laptop without cable and stay aware of the battery.

Comment: Oh no :(@Sempie it doesn't work I just checked,I guess only option would be to set-up a notification then?

Comment: Mh =/ Thank you anyway. His laptop already notifies him when batterie gets low, but he wants to check it in realtime.  For most other users, your solution should do well so I vote it up, but don't accept it as correct answer.

Comment: @Sempie Thanks but I will look further if there is any software that will work based on what you are saying

Comment: Anything new there?